# Joomla itemid redirect url

Tags: php, redirect, joomla

I have a joomla 3.3.1 site and have attached different articles on home page as a featured article. Now by clicking those article link (image, header text) its redirect you the following link under `(\components\com_content\views\featured\tmpl\default_item.php)` line no. 28:

`<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid)); ?>">`

And if you open that link from frontend, it will show like this depends of the article id:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=22:small-minds&catid=10&Itemid=101
```

Now I want to redirect that Itemid from `Itemid=101` to somewhere else like (`Itemid=134` or `Itemid=164`). So for that what code I need to put down in that `default_item.php` code so that it can redirect my desired `Itemid` that I set from there.

I have tried to write down the following code:

`<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid). $menuItemId=44); ?>">`

And if I open the link on the frontend, its showing something like that:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=22:small-minds&catid=10&Itemid=10144
```

And I want it to be show something like this:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=22:small-minds&catid=10&Itemid=44
```

As you can see the both Item id are showing instead of the one that I have given (44) later. So need your help on this.

Comment: 1. don't hack core files. 2. Why not use Joomla's built-in redirect mechanism?

Comment: @cppl I need to change the core settings. I can't use redirect on this. I have modified my code. Can you help me out?

Comment: You need to override them not change them. Don't edit the core files use the MVC to do what you want.

Comment: Is this something you need to do on a small number of files or do you need to do it dynamically for many files? Before you do anything make sure you understand the routing system but if it is a small number of files I would possibly not do the core readme link and instead hard code the link right in your article. Alternatively make direct menu links to the items on the featured page.

Comment: @Elin I just need to do a small number of files. I won't use that structure (featured article default_item.php file) anywhere in the site except in one place and that's why I need the hard code link. I want to put the Itemid fixed on that particular page and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Literally add a span or div with the hard coded id ... like this 
`index.php?Itemid=44`  that is all you need if it is a direct menu link generating the Itemid. If there is no menu link then you will want to write out the dynamic url and append the Itemid to it.  For a limited number of files it is going to be best to make the menu link to each file directly. It's more work but you'll have total control.

Comment: @Elin I can't do that the way you suggested. If there is one article then I could put the hard code in that way you mentioned like start index.php? but here it would be 10-12 features articles and it can be changed time to time. So article id would be dynamic here and and Itemid would be fixed. All I need is to change the Itemid. Rest of the structure need to be same to make it work.

Comment: Do you definitely know the itemId meaning is it permanent?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to consider is why you want to change the Itemid.  The current value is coming from the featured menu item.  This gives you many options for the drill down to the items.  What are you accomplishing by changing the Itemid? Are you trying to control the template, the modules, the urls or something else?

The Itemid is an extremely important concept in Joomla because it governs template, modules, urls, and numerous other things depending on the options chosen.  The SEF plugin also searches for matching Itemids using complex hierarchical rules.

Here is the problem.  You do not want to have different itemids for the same content. If the page is very different it is fine, but otherwise you need to be very cautious about everything once you start messing with the default system.

If you absolutely permanently know the value of the Itemid and know what you are doing and it's the same itemId for all of the articles, then what you can do is make a layout override for the featured view that replaces the dynamically generated readmore with hard coding. Also change the title links if you have linked titles. If you do this you may also need to override the layouts for articles and blogs for those articles depending on your views on duplicate content.

If the problem is that you are doing something special on the featured page and you don't want that on the inside pages you are better off making the feature view the one you make adjustments to (that is for example make the normal template the default and the special one for featured only used with that menu link).  Also, if the issue is modules you may be better off with different templaes of by hiding/displaying certain modules depending on if you are in the feature view.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But its not help me to solve my problem. I am well aware of Itemid functionality etc and I have clearly mentioned that I won't going to use the Feature article (default_item.php) core page anywhere in the site. Never ever going to use that page. So I want the PHP code where by clicking h2 url it will redirect me a certain Itemid (not the by default itemid it is generating) where I have placed some functionality. My itemid is 101 right now. And after modifying some code its redirecting 10144 but i want only 44. So can you help on this by writing down some php code??

Comment: I've explained to you what you have to do, you will have to make an override and not use jroute. You will also have to make sure that no where in the menu tree is there any parent category link to the articles since those will pull in other item ids.  You have a finite set of options and you haven't even explained where this  item id is coming from or what you are trying to achieve by using it.  Joomla is going to try to keep you from generating duplicate content and so you are going to have to force it.